# converting txt file to dictionary to count ".csv"

Tags: python, dictionary, txt

`I have to count ".csv" in each line and assign them to the same key value.

I have text file "files.txt" with 7 line of

```
test/file1.txt    
test/file2.txt.gz      
test/file3.csv     
test/file4.txt     
test2/file5.csv        
test2/file6.txt     
test2/file7.csv
```

Here's my code:

```
res = {}
for line in open('files.txt').readlines():
    key, val = line.strip().split('/')
    x =0
    if '.csv' in val:
        x+=1
        print(key, ":", x)
```

which yields the following output:

```
test : 1      
test2 : 1    
test2: 1
```

notice that I am new to programing`

Comment: You forgot to show the code you're struggling with

Comment: press `ctrl + A` to highlight all code, press `ctrl + C` to copy it, then [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/75670334/edit) this question, and press `ctrl + V` to paste the code, this shouldn't need a tutorial.

Comment: My bad it keeps giving me text problems

Comment: Furthermore, please state clearly your expected output ('assign them to the same key value' is quite vague). Also, your code is incoherent with your examples (you split on '/', whereas the separator is ':')

Comment: Please post code, data, and results as text, not screenshots. [Why should I not upload images of code/data/errors?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-should-i-not-upload-images-of-code-data-errors) http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode

Comment: Use `Collections.counter()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here, I've kept your code intact, but made used of the `res` dictionary to count the total number of occurrences of '.csv' for each key:

```
res = {}
for line in open('files.txt').readlines():
    key, val = line.strip().split('/')
    if '.csv' in val:
        res[key] = res.get(key, 0) + 1
for key, val in res.items():
    print(f"{key}:{val}")

# test:1
# test2:2
```